# How to send ether to erc721 token owner?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I want to send ether to token owner.

`ownerOf` returns address, so I set payable address inside of `sendEther` function.

However, error says 'Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable'.

Is there any way to set payable address inside function?
Could you give me any advise?

```
  function sendEther(uint256 _tokenId) public payable {
    address payable _tokenOwner = ownerOf(_tokenId);
    _tokenOwner.transfer(msg.value);
  }

ERC721.sol
    function ownerOf(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (address) {
        address owner = _tokenOwner[tokenId];
        return owner;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly cast from `address` to `address payable`, but you can cast in two steps, through `uint160`:

```
address payable _tokenOwner = address(uint160(ownerOf(_tokenId)));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! I didn't know that uint160 equivalent to address.